# How to teleport an item to a player in Minecraft 1.13?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

In Minecraft pre-release 3 I was able to run the command
`/execute as @e[type=item,name="Big Apple"] run tp @e[tag=bigapple] @s` and it would find an item dropped on the ground named Big Apple and it would teleport it to me. Now in Minecraft 1.13 official release it doesn't work. Please help!

Comment: What does it do instead?

Comment: I think your execute function is messing things up, so you probably will want to stick with what Xav said, and only use a tp. Also, are you trying to tp something with the *tag* Big Apple or *name* Big Apple, because the tp section of the code you put in uses the tag not name. Using name and executing as yourself: `tp @e[type=item,name="Big Apple"] @s`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this command:

```
/tp @e[type=item,limit=1,name=item_name] @p
```

It is example command:

```
/tp @e[type=item,limit=1,name=Stone] @p
```

Answer (score 0):

You should just be able to use:

```
tp @e[tag=bigapple] @s
```

and that will teleport any entity with the tag 'bigapple' to the executor of the command.

NOTE: Ensure this is being run on the command line, not in a command block. @s will not work in a command block without the appropriate selector.

Comment: No, he wants to teleport something to the item.

Comment: "[It] would find an item dropped on the ground named Big Apple and it would teleport it to me". His code teleports the item to itself, but I think he wants to teleport the item to himself.

Answer (score 0):

You're running the @e identifier as a tag, not a name. From looking at it that's what I can see. Just change what you're teleporting as a tag to a name instead, as you haven't given the "Big Apple" a tag, only a name, so it can't teleport what to the game technically doesn't exist.

Hope that helps!